# Move recurring @RequestParams somewhere before Controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-restcontroller

I have multiple endpoints in my `RestController`s that follow some similar signature:

```java
@GetMapping
public SomeItem get(@RequestParam String sortBy, 
                    @RequestParam String sortField, 
                    @RequestParam int pageNumber,
                    @RequestParam int pageSize) {
  QueryOptions queryOptions = QueryOptions.of(sortyBy, sortField, pageNumber, pageSize);
  // ...
}
```

I was wondering if there is a way of removing this code duplication from all the different methods and move the `QueryOptions` construction somewhere before the `RestController` method, so that I could use a method like the following:

```java
@GetMapping
public SomeItem get(QueryOptions queryOptions) {
  // ...
}
```

How can I do this? Maybe adding a filter in the filterchain?

Comment: It should work out of the box. What specific problem are you facing?

Comment: Indeed, I now see that it's possible to accept an Object whose properties are made up of `@RequestParam` values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that this is supported out of the box:

```java
@Getter
@Setter
public class QueryOptions {
  private String pageNumber;
  private String pageSize;
  private String orderBy;
  private String sortField;
}
```

And then you can accept this Class in the Controller method:

```java
@GetMapping
public SomeItem get(QueryOptions queryOptions) {
  // ...
}
```